# Filter same Value Map to show specific values in different columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, sql-view, multi-values

I am using QGIS 3.12.2 on Windows 10. I have created one large table layer to use as a ValueMap for multiple columns in a project. I need each column to show only the relevant values.

I have tried to add constraints but it only applies as validation on the selected values while each column still shows the full list.

Is there a way to limit the ValueMap list view to only a portion of the available values?

Comment: I currently have no real idea, what you're trying to do. Can you provide a screenshot of you current map and an example of what you're aiming at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems you are trying to filter a table layer to provide in a form a list of choices. Although you can use "Value Map", if you want to get from one layer more than one list of choices, you should better use "Value Relation" instead of "Value Map" and here filter your list depending of conditions. Below, you can see a screenshot where we use a simple condition but you can use a more complex one

[image: Expression in Value Relation]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.